# How to order integers according to size and track their positions by variable name

Tags: visual-studio, c#-2.0

I have a program with multiple int variables where individual counts are added to the specific variable each time a set fail condition is encountered. I want the user to be able to track how many failures of each category they have encountered by a button click. I want to display the range on a datagridview in order from highest value integer down to lowest. I also need to display in the adjacent column the name of the test step that relates to the value. My plan was to use Array.sort to order the integers but i then lose track of their names so cant assign the adjacent string column. I tried using a hashtable but if i use the string as a key it sorts alphabetically not numerically and if i use the integer as a key i get duplicate entries which dont get added to the hash table. here is some of the examples i tried but they have the aforementioned problems. essentially i want to end with two arrays where the order matches the naming and value convention. FYI the variables were declared before this section of code, variables ending in x are the string name for the (non x) value of the integer.

```
    Hashtable sorter = new Hashtable();

      sorter[download] = downloadx;
      sorter[power] = powerx;
      sorter[phase] = phasex;
      sorter[eeprom] = eepromx;
      sorter[upulse] = upulsex;
      sorter[vpulse] = vpulsex;
      sorter[wpulse] = wpulsex;
      sorter[volts] = voltsx;
      sorter[current] = currentx;
      sorter[ad] = adx;
      sorter[comms] = commsx;
      sorter[ntc] = ntcx;
      sorter[prt] = prtx;

      string list = "";
      string[] names = new string[13];
      foreach (DictionaryEntry child in sorter)
      {
          list += child.Value.ToString() + "z";      
      }
      int[] ordered = new int[] { download, power, phase, eeprom, upulse, vpulse, wpulse, volts, current, ad, comms, ntc, prt };

      Array.Sort(ordered);
      Array.Reverse(ordered);


      for (int i = 0; i < sorter.Count; i++)
      {
          int pos = list.IndexOf("z");
          names[i] = list.Substring(0, pos);
          list = list.Substring(pos + 1);

      }
```

First question here so hope its not too longwinded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary. And you can order it by the value : myDico.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Reverse(), the sort will be numerical descending. You just have to enumerate the result.
I hope I understand your need. Otherwise ignore me.

Comment: Hi Toto thanks for a quick reply. I am very new to C# so dont fully understand your response, will this dictionary function require a using directive? Also i did think enumeration was the was to do this but the net examples i tried dont compile, again does this require a using directive also.

Comment: Check out OrderByDescending. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx

Comment: Hi sq33G, Sorry for such a late reply. I have the corrrect using statement for dictionary, but when i try using dictionary my results can only be sorted by key not value, since my integers can sometimes be the same value i cant use them as a key otherwise this would be duplicate dictionary entries, this means that i can only sort my results alphabetically by string as opposed to displaying them in descending numerical order. My results are being displayed using a datagrid view. The idea is to have column 1 listing the name of the failed test and column 2 listing the number of times failed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using a

```
Dictionary <string, int>
```

to store your numbers.I'm not clear on how you're displaying results at the end - do you have a grid or a list control?

You ask about usings. Which ones do you already have?

**EDIT** for .NET 2.0

There might be a more elegant solution, but you could implement the logic by putting your rows in a DataTable. Then you can make a DataView of that table and sort by whichever column you like, ascending or descending.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=VS.80).aspx for example.

**EDIT** for .NET 3.5 and higher

As far as sorting a Dictionary by its values:

```
var sortedEntries = myDictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value);
```

If you need the results to be a Dictionary, you can call `.ToDictionary()` on that. For reverse order, use `.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value)`.

Comment: Hi sq33G, Sorry for such a late reply.

Comment: I  am not able to use the var keyword or the orderby method from dictionary as i am using visual studio 2005. From what i have read these functions plus others such as linq are not available in this edition. is it possible to install a reference to upgrade VS2005 to be compatible or am i forced to live with a lack of features. I know VS2008 /10 are available free as express editions but for works purposes im tied to 2005. Any ideas on alternative approaches perhaps. Thanks so much for your input so far.